# Google Maps - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have a jQuery Mobile site and also have Google maps currently running on multiple pages.  The problem I have is when I navigate between pages, the map won't render again (only loads on the first page selected). The page needs to be refreshed before it will load again.  What am I missing?

```
jQuery("div:jqmData(role='page'):last").live('pageinit', function(){
    initialize();
});

jQuery("div:jqmData(role='page'):last").live('pageinit', function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setOptions(options); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `google.maps.event.trigger(mapObj, "resize");` on `pageshow` or `pagechange` instead of `pageinit`.